# Change Button textFill property in javafx

Tags: button, javafx

Using javafx, I have a button which in the css properties has the textFill set to white. Then during runtime it needs to be changed, which happens with this code:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class QAButton extends Button {

    public QAButton(String text) {
        this.textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public void setAnswerVisible(Boolean vis) {

        if (vis) this.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        else this.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

However it doesn't do anything, the textFill will stay white. What can I do to change it during runtime?
Thank you.

Edit: I should add the css code:

```
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

And the button's id is set to

```
#question {
    -fx-background-color: darkblue;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-max-width: 2000px;
    -fx-max-height: 200px;
    -fx-min-height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extraction from [JavaFX CSS Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) (second section):

> "The implementation allows designers to style an application by using style sheets to override property values set from code."

The *setStyle* API can fix your problem.

Example:

```
this.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green");
```

Now **all** attributes in the style class will be overwritten.
If this is a problem, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385117/using-both-css-and-setstyle).