# JavaFX - TextField prompt text doesn't get deleted upon focus after changing color

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

When I change the color of the `prompt-text`, either via `setStyle()` or directly through `CSS`, when I click on the `TextField`, first of all, it won't auto-clear it and because of it, the "bar" that usually pops when you're about to write in a field is all the way to the left - as you can see in the following pictures:

[image: Focused first text field]
[image: Focused second text field]

- In the first picture the `Username TextField` is focused, which has its `prompt-text` color changed to `#000000` (black).
- In the second picture the `Password TextField` is focused, which has default `prompt-text` settings. Nothing is changed about it.

I looked through the JavaFX API Documentation, numerous StackOverflow cases about the `TextFields` in general, CSS cases on other forums, the `modena.css` (`.text-input`) and so on. I haven't seen anywhere someone with a problem like mine where the solution proposed has worked for me.

In most cases people suggest to use `-fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;`, but that makes all of `prompt-texts` everywhere empty regardless of whether they're focused or not.

Some of the variations I tried as well for the `text-input Class` are these:

```
.text-input, .text-input:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 0%);
}

.text-input .text-input:focused {
        -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}

.text-input, .text-input:focused {
        -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

I've spent 8-10h looking and trying to figure out a solution, but I'm just not knowledge-able enough about JavaFX/CSS. Some help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

```
.text-input {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: <your-color>;
}

.text-input:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

This works, but it's applied to all `TextFields`. Not to a specific one, which is what I'm looking for.

```
#myId {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: <your-color>;
}

#myId:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

This also works, as long as I leave it as is. When I click a button that does only this: `txtUsername.setStyle("-fx-prompt-text-fill: " + returnColorValueInHex(colorPickerValue) + ";");`, the color changes but then it seems to ignore the `myId:focused`. Like it's not there.

```
.my-styleclass {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: <your-color>;
}

.my-styleclass:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

This works as well, but when I apply the above mentioned `setStyle()`, the same thing as when working with the `ID` happens. It ignores the `focused` part in the CSS.

I found this example that works with bindings.

```
txtUsername.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.when(txtUsername.focusedProperty())
                            .then("-fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;")
                            .otherwise("-fx-prompt-text-fill: " + returnColorValueInHex(colorPickerValue) + ";"));
```

It does exactly what I want it to do, but I'd like to avoid using it and only styling the CSS if possible.

Why? I'm trying to make an application that people can customize. I'd like them to be able to change colors of certain parts of the application and the `prompt-text` of `TextField` is one of them. I use `setStyle()` to apply changes so they can preview it. Once they click "Save", all of the applied styles are to be saved in a `.css` file and then the program will load that file as it's `stylesheet` once restarted.

**EDIT 2:** Found a solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385117/using-both-css-and-setstyle)

**CSS:**

```
.root{
    username-prompt-text-fill: #000000;
}
#txtUsername{
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: username-prompt-text-fill;
}
#txtUsername:focused{
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

**JAVA:**

```
txtUsername.setStyle("username-prompt-text-fill: " + returnColorValueInHex(colorPickerValue) + ";");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385117/using-both-css-and-setstyle) and **Slaws'** answer helped me get to the solution of my problem.

**CSS:**

```
.root{
    username-prompt-text-fill: <color>;
}
#txtUsername{
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: username-prompt-text-fill;
}
#txtUsername:focused{
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

**JAVA:**

```
txtUsername.setStyle("username-prompt-text-fill: " + returnColorValueInHex(colorPickerValue) + ";");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS to customize the prompt text fill while still having it disappear when focused:

```css
.text-input {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: <your-color>;
}

.text-input:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

If you want to target a specific `TextField`, give it an ID and target the ID in the CSS file.

```
textField.setId("myId");
```

```css
#myId {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: <your-color>;
}

#myId:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

If many `TextField`s should have the same style, consider giving them all a custom style class.

```
textField.getStyleClass().add("my-styleclass");
```

```css
.my-styleclass {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: <your-color>;
}

.my-styleclass:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

*Note: The `id`/style classes can be set/added via FXML as well. If you use `fx:id` only, the `id` will be the same value, otherwise `id` is used for CSS and `fx:id` is used for field injection.*

---

For more information, see [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: That works, but it's applied to all `TextFields`. I tried things like `#txtUsername .text-input{-fx-prompt-text-fill: red;}`, `#txtUsername .text-input:focused{-fx-prompt-text-fill: red;}`, `#txtUsername-Login:focused{-fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;}`, `.text-input #txtUsername{-fx-prompt-text-fill: red;}`, `.text-input:focused #txtUsername{-fx-prompt-text-fill: red;}`, and last but not least I tried changing the color of the `prompt-text` of the `txtUsername` and only leaving the `text-input:focused` - but it won't work on that specific `TextField`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I've updated my original question (EDIT 1) to add more info on what I've tried and what works/doesn't since I don't have enough characters here.

Comment: Found a solution, but I'd like to thank you for helping out as well. ^_^